# Will the original object change if you pass object as parameter to a function inside another file?

Tags: javascript

If you update an object you pass as a parameter will it be updated "upwards", if the method that gets the parameter is in another file? Or will the object you passed down as a parameter have its own context?

Comment: Where the method is is immaterial, and updates don't have a direction.

Comment: What do you mean "another file"? A separate .js file that is used along with the same page that the object was created in or a completely separate .html page?

Comment: It doesn't matter from which source file a function was compiled from, there are no such "contexts" in JavaScript. Yes, objects are reference values, it doesn't get copied when passed into a function - and when you mutate it that means you're mutating the single original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's updated too. In JavaScript you're actually passing objects' references not the objects themselves.

```js
let obj = {
  foo: 'bar'
};

function func(arg) {
  arg.foo = 'hi';
}
func(obj);
console.log(obj.foo); // prints 'hi'
```